# How can I cast a delegate that takes a derived-type argument to a delegate with a base-type argument?

Tags: c#

Consider the code:

```
public interface IGeneral {}
public interface ISpecific : IGeneral {}
public Func<IGeneral, String> Cast(Object specificFuncAsObject) {
      var generalFunc = specificFuncAsObject as Func<IGeneral, String>;
      Assert.IsNotNull(generalFunc); // <--- casting didn't work
      return generalFunc;
}

Func<ISpecific, String> specificFunc = specific => "Hey!";
var generalFunc = Cast(specificFunc);
```

Is there a way to make such casting work? I know that IGeneral cannot be casted to ISpecific in general case. But in my particular situation I wish I could do something like this:

```
 Func<IGeneral, String> generalFunc = new Func<IGeneral, String>(general => specificFunc(general as ISpecific));
```

But having the `specificFunc` as Object and having `ISpecific` type only via `specificFuncAsObject.GetType()`

Comment: You can create a wrapping lambda method, but if I'm reading this right at first glance I think you'll have to cast: `generalFunc = general => specificFunc((ISpecific)general);` Otherwise as a `Func<IGeneral, string>` you could pass in some `IOtherSpecific` and things will fall apart because `specificFunc` wanted an `ISpecific`, _not_ an `IGeneral` or `IOtherSpecific`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is impossible, think of the following case:

```
class Base
{
}

class DerivedA : Base
{
}

class DerivedB : Base
{
}
```

With the some methods:

```
string DoSomething(DerivedA myDerived)
{
}
```

Then, somewhere you have code:

```
Func<DerivedA, string> functionA = DoSomething;
// Let's assume this cast is possible...
Func<Base, string> functionBase = (Func<BaseB, string>) functionA;

// At this point, the signature of the function that functionBase is assigned to
// is actually `string DoSomething(DerivedA myDerived)`
functionB(new DerivedB());
// If the cast is allowed, then passing a DerivedB should be allowed, but this makes
// absolutely no sense because the function is expecting a DerivedA.
```

What you can do is use a utility function to convert with a cast (or `as` operator if you wish):

```
Func<Base, string> Convert<T>(Func<T, string> function) where T : Base
{
return x => function(x as T);
}
```

And then do something like:

```
Func<DerivedA, string> functionA = DoSomething;
Func<Base, string> functionBase = Convert(functionA);
```

Answer (score 9):

`T` (the input type) in [`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) is [contravariant, not covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx), so such a thing is not directly possible. You can, however, do the following:

```
Func<ISpecific, String> specificFunc = specific => "Hey!";
Func<IGeneral, String> generalFunc = general => specificFunc((ISpecific)general);
```

Or the reverse:

```
Func<IGeneral, String> generalFunc = general => "Hey!";
Func<ISpecific, String> specificFunc = generalFunc;
```